# How to find class that contains main method in a package/jar using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic-class-loaders

I am using dynamic class loading which requires the main class for loading the classes.
If have a package/jar i want to get the class name that contains main method?
Is it possible with Reflection? or is there any other API?

Is there any method like ***java.net.JarClassLoader.getMainClassName()*** for packages too.

Comment: Don't you have the `Main-Class` header in your `MANIFEST` file?

Answer (score 0):

You need a firm and first entry point (main method) then you can make all calls dynamically via reflection.

Comment: I have working code for the same.But i dont want to submit main class in my code. My program itself has to check for the main method..

Comment: A Java application needs a main method, and you can also have to deliver it. Classes and methods which you want to access then is just by reflection dynamically feasible

Comment: In case of java application i will input the main class name(Working). But in the case of Jar/Package i dont know which is the main class in it(I will specify Jar at Run time). Then my program has to get the main class in that Package/jar. So my question is about how do we get that main class?